# Trying to test my cifar-10 trained CNN with custom Airplane picture

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So after learning the **basics** of CNN with Keras in python i tried to add my own picture of an airplane to test my trained program. For this i tried to import an 1920x1080 png image, after some research i found a probable way to reshape the image, but i get following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/Programming Courses/Image_Classifier_Project/Model_Test.py", line 21, in 
>       img = np.reshape(img, [1, 32, 32, 3])
>     File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in reshape
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 301, in reshape
>       return _wrapfunc(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 61, in _wrapfunc
>       return bound(*args, **kwds)
>   ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1024 into shape (1,32,32,3)

The image is in color (as are the training ones).

Here is the code. I am calling my training results from a file.

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import keras.utils as utils
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Get Model Data
labels = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

(_, _), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.0
y_test = utils.to_categorical(y_test)

model = load_model('Classified.h5')

img = cv2.imread("a400m.png", 0)
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))

img = np.reshape(img, [1, 32, 32, 3])

# results = model.evaluate(x=x_test, y=y_test)
# print("Loss: ", results[0])
# print("Accuracy", results[1])

test_image_data = np.asarray(img)

prediction = model.predict(x=test_image_data)
print("Prediction: ", labels[np.argmax(prediction)])
# max_index = np.argmax(prediction[0])
# print("Prediction: ", labels[max_index])
```

Sorry for the messy code, just tried to implement it, rather than starting from scratch

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your image is in color, so you need to load it as a color image :

```
img = cv2.imread("a400m.png", 1)  # 0 means grayscale
```

Secondly :

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32)) #give a shape of (32, 32, 3)
```

This line will reshape your image of shape `(1920, 1080, 3)` to a shape of `(32, 32, 3)`.

Last, in order to predict on that image you need to have expand its dim, for that use numpy expand_dim fucntion :

```
img = np.expand_dims(img, 0) #give a shape of (1, 32, 32, 3), 0 means first dim
```

Comment: Oh ok got it! Cannot mark your answer right now as you were this fast, but it worked perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to have helped you !